# Is it possible for google cloud scheduler to push a list of data to pub/sub at a given frequency?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-scheduler

I would like a cloud function to be triggered by pub/sub at a given frequency (1 second).

Setting a scheduler like below can achieve this, but the `payload` that get sent to the pub/sub is always the same, so the cloud function triggered will always receive same input.

Is it possible to pass a list of data as payload, and push the elements of that list to pub/sub one by one at the frequency 1/sec? So the interval between cloud function being triggered is one second?

[image]

Comment: Cloud Scheduler's granularity is 60 seconds, not one second. For your second part, no you cannot push a list of data and have Cloud Scheduler select a part of send to Pub/Sub. You will need to create your own service for that level of specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass a list of data as payload

You can put whatever you want in that payload.  If you want a list, perhaps you could encode it as a JSON list or something similar that's easy to parse.

> and push the elements of that list to pub/sub one by one at the frequency 1/sec? So the interval between cloud function being triggered is one second?

That's too frequent.  The best you can do is get a rate of once every minute, according the specs in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way other than scheduler to make the cloud function to be triggered one per second or any interval?

Comment: There is no such supported mechanism in Google Cloud, other than implementing something yourself on a server instance you control.  Perhaps you can do a web search and find other mechanisms that behave the way you want.